# Can you change the character encoding in a bootloader or do you need a second one?

Tags: assembly, character-encoding, bootloader, bios

I'm trying to write a bootloader but I want to change the character set to have greek characters. For now the char encoding is extended ASCII. I know that some russian mbr ramsonwares have the text in that piece of code (which is 512 bytes). Or do I need a second bootloader and a minikernel?

Comment: Yes you can create support for different encodings if you like

Comment: i'm thinking that on the first stage the encoding depends on the motherboard you're using

Comment: The charset should be CP437 but the font is stored in bit-plane 2 of the VGA adaptor and can, thus, be replaced by the firmware or by the bootloader. Each char is 16 bytes. If you limit yourself to only the capital and lowercase letters, you need 16*48 = 768 bytes. Too much. You can however compress the fonts or limit yourself to a specific case (384 bytes). It's better to use a second stage.

Comment: yeah, indeed it is CP437. in that case i don't have possibilites and i have to do it in the second stage. thanks!

Comment: @OrestesColominaMonsalve Note that even CP437 has quite a few greek characters.  Perhaps it's sufficient for your needs.

Comment: yeah i've seen that, it does have the Spanish ñ. i was asking more of a curiosity and know how char encodings work and all that

Comment: @zx485 I think it's 16 byes, each char has a 8x16 bitmap. I brushed up on the format reading [this page on OSDev](https://wiki.osdev.org/VGA_Fonts#Get_from_VGA_RAM_directly).

Comment: @MargaretBloom: You're right. I totally misunderstood this question (and in the following, that part of your comment). Indeed, an interesting task. +1